# Common Interface to perform Detection algorithm

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I am stuck in a situation please help me out of this.

Thought:
To have a common Interface among different Detection algorithms(Say Circle, Triangle and Rectangle).

```
    class IDetectionInterface()
    {
    public:
          virtual void PerformDetection(Image & InputImage, DetectionStruct & DetectionData, DetectionParam & DetParam) = 0;
         virtual ~IDetectionInterface()
         {
         }
    };
```

where **Image** and **DetectionStruct** is a structure as below:

```
struct Image
{
    unsigned char * pImageData;
    int Width;
    int Height;
};

struct DetectionStruct
{
    Rect BoundingBox;
    DectionType DetType;
};

struct Rect
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

enum DectionType 
{
    Circle = 0,
    Triangle = 1,
    Rectangle = 2
}
```

The Problem for me is that of DetectionParam, as Parameters of Detection Algorithms differ. Say for example

```
struct RectDetectionParam
{
    int param1;
    float param2;
    double param3; 
};

struct TriDetectionParam
{
    float param1;
    float param2;
    double param3; 
    int param4;
};

struct CirDetectionParam
{
    int param1;
    float param2;
    bool param3; 
    int param4;
    float param5;
};
```

How can i get this to common interface as above.

Note: I don't want to put all the parameters in one structure which is a easiest solution, But it has its drawback if i change the algorithm then its respective parameters changes and we need to re write the structure again.

And Ofcource Yes, I will have the implementation of the interface(Abstract class)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many approaches to solve that problem. Using a discriminated `union` is one of the, Using a generic `std::map<std::string,std::any>` where the parameter name is used as key is another one.

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: As mentioned there would be many viable examples how to make generic parameter sets.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you could create a discriminated union to make the parameter sets generic:

```
 struct DetectionParams {
      DectionType detectionType; // Discriminator
      union {
           RectDetectionParam rectDect;
           TriDetectionParam triDect;
           CirDetectionParam cirDect;
      };
 };
```

Which of the union parts is used in the implementation is determined by the discriminator.

---

Another way is to use something like a parameter set based on unique parameter names (key strings):

```
  struct DetectionParams {
        std::map<std::string,std::any> params; // Note that std::any is available 
                                               // at the not yet official c++17 standard
  };
```